# Black screen after first boot of Ubuntu. Cannot enter nomodest mode

Tags: boot, grub2

I have successfully installed Ubuntu on an SSD from a flash drive (erasing all content during installation). And I see a black screen on the first book.

According to this answer [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) I am supposed to enter the nomodeset mode by pressing the Right Shift when booting up.

I tried holding the key continuously and hitting it repeatedly, etc. but all I get is a black screen.

I have an NVidia card.

Comment: Shift is for BIOS boot. With UEFI you press escape key after vendor logo, but before grub menu should appear. Sometimes you have to try several times. Also fast boot must be off in UEFI settings as that assumes no system changes and immediately boots giving no time to press any key.  Best to have installed using Safe Boot and then include optional restricted extras to install nVidia driver. Recovery mode or second line in grub menu includes nomodeset and gives you a recovery menu. Turn on Internet & install nVidia driver.  What brand/model system? What nvidia card/chip?

Comment: It is a Gigabyte PC which previously ran on Windows. This is my first installation of Linux, so I know very little (tried it in a virtual machine on the same computer which worked fine).
Card: GeForce GT 630. I have not been able to find the chip data.
I reverted to Windows for now, but want to have another go at Linux. Should I do it the same way as before and try Escape or could you direct me to the safe boot procedure, please?

Comment: Just select the option to install 3rd party drivers, etc. This will install the required Nvidia drivers. Also disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: I had a GT620 in my older Haswell based system. Turned out that Intel's Haswell chip was better GPU than older nVidia. You boot live installer from UEFI boot menu. It should show UEFI:flash drive as boot option. You should only need escape if Ubuntu does not boot and grub has not found Windows. Make sure Windows fast startup is off, also.

Comment: Changan, it makes sense. I carefully made sure that the option to install 3rd party drivers is selected but it did not help.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure whether it is BIOS or UEFI or what. I downloaded the Ubuntu file and followed their procedure.

Comment: hello @DenisKazakov can you explain a little bit further? Is it blank screen after booting or you not even see grub screen?

Comment: @jpbrain, it goes black after the first reboot after successful installation. I restarted the computer and could not get to any screen other the black blank screen.
Since then, I solved it by installing Linux Mint.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I Had a similar issue. solved with a parameter on grub as it could not show grub in graphics mode. "GRUB_TERMINAL = console"